# Do all outlets in detached workshop need to be tamper resistant?

Tags: receptacle, nec

Ok, I just failed my inspection.   The inspector made some good catches.  The only thing I question is he said all outlets in the detached workshop need to be tamper resistant.  We are still on the 2014 NEC, and I thought I only needed tamper resistant outlets in the house.  Does the shop really need TR outlets?

Comment: I don’t have the 14 code handy but the 17 code 406.12 states as required by 210.52  if you go all the way to G.1 garage in each attached and detached unless more than 5-1/2’ above the floor I believe the 14 code has a similar provision , tamper resistant receptacles are routinely forgotten about by internet electricians. Since the text is not highlighted except a few words this is not new so it was code in 14 also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is required by the 2014 NEC, the 2014 Code says:

406.12 Tamper-Resistant Receptacles. Tamper-resistant receptacles shall be installed as specified in 406.12(A) through (C).

(A) Dwelling Units. In all areas specified in 210.52, all nonlocking-type 125-volt, 15- and 20-ampere receptacles shall be listed tamper-resistant receptacles.

Comment: Thanks.  I was wondering if a detached workshop qualified as a "dwelling unit".

Comment: If you don't have a copy of the 2014 edition you can view it at https://www.nfpa.org/codes-and-standards/all-codes-and-standards/list-of-codes-and-standards/detail?code=70 , click free access, then change to year you wish to view.

Comment: 210.52 includes residential "accessory buildings", so if power is fed by your resident, property is zoned, and property occupancy is only approved as residential then 406.12 would apply.